# How to fix '[stderr]' output from sed command in BeforeInstall script when writing to the php.ini file for activating the imagick php extension?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, imagick, stderr, aws-code-deploy

Attempting to use AWS CodeDeploy to for a PHP Symfony app.

Running into an issue with the BeforeInstall script.

BeforeInstall Script(install server dependencies) shown below.

The script is being executed as root user so unclear if there is a permissions issue.

I have attempted an running alternative version with `sudo sed...` to no avail.

> appspec.yml

```
version: 0.0
os: linux 
files:
  - source: content/
    destination: /var/www/html/
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/install_server_dependencies.sh
      timeout: 1000
      runas: root
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/install_app_dependencies.sh
      timeout: 1000
      runas: root
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/start_server.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: scripts/stop_server.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
```

> install_server_dependencies.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Navigate to public web directory
cd /var/www/html/

# Install Server Dependencies
yum -y update
yum -y install httpd24
yum -y install php73
yum -y install php73-devel
yum -y install php73-mysql
yum -y install php73-pgsql
yum -y install php73-pdo
yum -y install php73-mbstring
yum -y install php73-mcrypt 
yum -y install php73-pecl-gd
yum -y install php-pecl-imagick
yum -y install ImageMagick

# Store PHP Initialization file location
PHP_INI_PATH='/etc/php-7.3.d/php.ini' 

# Activate extensions
if ! grep -Fxq 'extension=imagick.so' ${PHP_INI_PATH}; then
    module_settings=$(cat ${PHP_INI_PATH} | grep -n '; Module Settings ;' | grep -o '^[0-9]*')
    dynamic_extensions=$((module_settings - 2))
    sed -i ${dynamic_extensions}'i\'$'\n''extension=imagick.so'$'\n' ${PHP_INI_PATH}
fi
```

I expected the output to install server dependencies and activate the imagick extension before the AfterInstall script performed composer install.

The following output is displayed in the CodeDeploy console.

```
Error code
ScriptFailed
Script name
scripts/install_server_dependencies.sh
Message
Script at specified location: scripts/install_server_dependencies.sh run as user root failed with exit code 4
```

```
[stderr] --follow-symlinks
[stderr] follow symlinks when processing in place; hard links
[stderr] will still be broken.
[stderr] -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
[stderr] edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied).
[stderr] The default operation mode is to break symbolic and hard links.
[stderr] This can be changed with --follow-symlinks and --copy.
[stderr] -c, --copy
[stderr] use copy instead of rename when shuffling files in -i mode.
[stderr] While this will avoid breaking links (symbolic or hard), the
[stderr] resulting editing operation is not atomic. This is rarely
[stderr] the desired mode; --follow-symlinks is usually enough, and
[stderr] it is both faster and more secure.
[stderr] -l N, --line-length=N
[stderr] specify the desired line-wrap length for the `l' command
[stderr] --posix
[stderr] disable all GNU extensions.
[stderr] -r, --regexp-extended
[stderr] use extended regular expressions in the script.
[stderr] -s, --separate
[stderr] consider files as separate rather than as a single continuous
[stderr] long stream.
[stderr] -u, --unbuffered
[stderr] load minimal amounts of data from the input files and flush
[stderr] the output buffers more often
[stderr] --help display this help and exit
[stderr] --version output version information and exit
[stderr]
[stderr]If no -e, --expression, -f, or --file option is given, then the first
[stderr]non-option argument is taken as the sed script to interpret. All
[stderr]remaining arguments are names of input files; if no input files are
[stderr]specified, then the standard input is read.
[stderr]
[stderr]GNU sed home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/>.
[stderr]General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
```